# Can I go from a 3-prong outlet and connect to a 2-prong outlet and switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have rewired the first 2 outlet in a circuit with 14-2 wire.  However, I do NOT want to rewire the rest of the circuit because it is inside non-accessible walls.  The rest of the circuit is a front door light with switch and an upstairs outlet.  Is it okay to re-connect the new 14-2 with to old non-grounded, cloth-covered with 2 wires?

Answer (score 1):

If the 2 prong receptacles are existing receptacles, there shouldn't be a problem. As long as you realize the 2 prong receptacles will not have a ground, and you don't replace the 2 prong receptacles with 3 prong receptacles.